# how do i can re-size revolution slider?

Tags: plugins, jquery-plugins, wordpress

I am using classified engine theme for my WordPress website durentme.com in which I want the half size slider from default size and want to place categories up in front of slider like renttycoons.com. I tried to much in css and coding but I am failed to find any solution to my problem.

How do I reduce the size of Revolution Slider on my website and how do I get categories up in front of the slider?

Answer (score 0):

slider size can be maintained from the backed just look for its menu in admin select the slide and the options should be there.

Hope it helps